# Не работает transition при right 0

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Добрый день.

Есть такая проблема при наведении на блок с `position: absolute` он должен плавно переехать в правую сторону `right: 0`, но у меня не получается это сделать думал что `transition` это исправит.

Вот код https://jsfiddle.net/j9zz6uxp/

```
.position{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 66px;
    background: red;
    top: 20px;
    left: 120px;
    margin-left: -28px;
    transition: all 1.1s;
    z-index: 999;
}

.position:hover{
    margin-left:auto;
    right: 0;
}
```

Прошу вашей помощи.

Comment: Ничего хорошего у вас таким образом не получится. При наведении блок уедет в сторону и малейшее шевеление мышкой вернет его обратно; или если шевеление будет в рамках движения блока, то у вас будет постоянное подергивание блока. На вашем месте, я бы переформулировал задачу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.position{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 66px;
    background: red;
    top: 20px;
    left: 120px;
    margin-left: -28px;
    transition: all 1.1s ease-in-out;
    z-index: 999;
}

.position:hover{
  margin-left:auto;
  left: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="position">

</div>
```

Вы с `left` на `right` меняете св-во при наведении, а нужно что-то одно

Comment: Решение рабочее, но, ребята, прекратите вешать "all" в transition и анимировать св-ва, которые не используют аппаратное ускорение.

Comment: Браузер должен знать точно что нужно анимировать.
При transition: all вы получите как минимум непредсказуемую анимацию, ещё и хуже производительность самой анимации.
На этом примере может заметно и не будет, но если у вас страница с несколькими +/- тяжёлыми анимациями, проседать будет ощутимо.

Comment: @UFleming, никогда еще не подводил all, но спасибо за разъяснение!

Comment: Он и не подводит особо. Это уже просто тонкости работы с анимация, как и св-во will-change. Не использовать all - это хорошая и полезная привычка.

Comment: @UFleming, спасибо учту

Answer (score 2):

Transition не работает, так как, вы не определили `right` у `.position`. Чтобы он стал работать, можно сделать так:

```css
.position{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    width: 56px;
    height: 66px;
    background: red;
    top: 20px;
    right: calc(100vw - 120px);
    margin-left: -28px;
    transition: all 3s;
    z-index: 999;
}

.position:hover{
  margin-left:auto;
  transition: all 3s;
  right: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="position">

</div>
```